# How many monthly pageviews does it take to have an Alexa ranking of 100,000? Or 50,000 or 10,000?

Tags: seo, alexa

Currently my website gets about 60,000 visitors per month and has an Alexa ranking of 350,000.

I'm curious if there's any data on what a website that has an Alexa ranking of 100,000 gets for monthly visitors. What about a ranking of 50,000 or even 10,000?

Comment: Alexa is notoriously poor at estimating traffic and rank. My advice is to forget Alexa. However, there is no number. A site with just 400 daily users can appear in the top 100,000 while another site with 20,000 daily users cannot. It is highly skewed toward users of the toolbar and sites that appeal to that audience. This would be blogs with a high social media profile and an emphasis on what the young want- celebrities, pop-stars, etc.

Comment: My site gets about 460,000 visits, 85% unique per month and is listed at around Alexa 60,000. A similar site to Alexa, SimilarWeb, says my site only gets 230,000 visits per month.

Comment: One may take a look at http://www.rank2traffic.com/, which gives good estimates of traffic based on alexa ranking.

Answer (score 2):

I have a site that ranks about 10,000 in Alexa.  It gets 8 million visitors each month.

Comment: base on my recent research, a website with alexa 100 000 has should have estimated traffic like this: 170 Thousand
(Desktop sessions per month)
320 Thousand
(Desktop+Mobile sessions)